# Where was super() called from?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

On a form data source (SalesLine) I have a `validateWrite` method, which in turn calls the `super()` method to call the `validateWrite` method on the SalesLine table, amongst other checks.

In the SaleLine table I have custom functionality for recording, and sometime stopping, data changes.

I don't want this functionality to be triggered when I write to SalesLine from my new form. Therefore **I want to check a condition, within the `validateWrite` method on the SalesLine table, to find out if the `validateWrite` was called form my new form**. This will allow me to skip the data change recording/stopping if the SalesLine write was called from my new form.

What is the correct approach?

I could create a boolean `recordSaveChecks` and set it before calling `SalesLine.write()`, but is there a better way?

**Edit: To clarify, I do not have form specific custom verification to add, I have a system-wide verification (therefore sits on the SaleLine Table), which needs to be skipped when called from from 1 specific form.**

Comment: I have noticed something called this.isFormDataSource() - I think I need something similar, but which returns the form maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best option may be to move the customization that is form specific onto the form's data source rather than on the table itself.  But if you true want to add form-specific code to the table, you can see an example in **Tables\Address.update()**, where it checks **this.dataSource().formRun().name()** to determine if it has been called from the relevant form.

Comment: I do not have "form specific" customisation, I have "system wide" customisation which needs to be skipped when called from 1 specific form. Therefore this.dataSource().formRun().name() is exactly what I need, thanks.

Comment: Actually Vince, I have just looked at Address.update() and it is the perfect example. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your code on the `SalesLine` `DataSource` in the `ValidateWrite()` method, before the super call Something like this:

```
ret = YourCheckGoesHere;

if(ret)
{
   ret = super();
}
else
{
    info("Why validation failed goes here");
}
   return ret;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not adding a check to validateWrite, I want to conditionally skip some existing functionality. As this functionality is needed across the rest of the system when writing to SalesLine, it must sit in the validateWrite method of the SalesLine Table.

Comment: What I am showing you here is that you can, on the new form you are creating, stop the form from calling super so that it skips your code on the Sales Line Table's validate write method. You can run your own validation on the form and never call super.

Comment: But then I would have to replicate the entire validateWrite method from the salesTable to remove a couple of lines. And if anyone adds validation to the table SalesLine validateWrite method in the future, it will need adding in 2 places. Not good!!!!

Comment: I am not sure why you would need to be making so many changes to the SalesLine Table's validate write method. In most cases if you have a form that is using SalesLine as a dataSource, you would do your validation on the form itself. You shouldn't be creating validation on the salesLine table (that will have to get checked for every update to a salesLine) for something that is form specific.

Comment: The only real validation that is performed on the SalesLine Table in Base AX is a call to ValidateWrite_Server which only calls salesLineType = this.type();

Comment: For performance reasons, you should try to avoid adding to much code on the table methods. If you are making changes to a form that contains a datasource, you should perform your validation on the form. This will allow you to skip the additional validation that you have put into the SalesLine Table's validateWrite method.

Comment: As I have said, I am not implementing any new verification. It has been a business requirement implemented by a VAR and live across multiple companies. All changes to the SalesLine table are logged with a reason code. Therefore this is implemented against the SaleLine table so it doesn't need to be in every place that a sales line can be user-modified. Except of course we now have one exception where the reason code needs to be ignored. It would not make sense to implement the logging everywhere that SalesLine can be changed just because there is one exception. Vince's solution is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Then you've implemented the validation logic into Table not into the Form because you need  the validation to be system wide but you need to prevent this validation when Insert/Update the record.

I think you can by override write() method of Form DataSource and use `SalesLine.doInsert();` and `SalesLine.doUpdate();`

Comment: Please do not use code highlighting to emphasize words; it should only be used for actual code.

Comment: hey this is a year old, and overriding write() would skip any other system wide checks, so this would not be good at all. See my comments on mike brown's answer for more background